# Wrong output when i run with this Merge sort code

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, mergesort

**I have implemented merge sort algorithm. I debugged the code properly.
 but not able to identify what is the problem with my code.
Here is my code :**

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void merge(int* l,int nL,int* r,int nR,int * a){
    //merging the arrays
    int i=0,j=0,k=0;
    while(i<nL && j<nR){
        if(l[i]<=r[j]){
            i++;
            a[k]=l[i];
        }

        else{
            j++;
            a[k]=r[j];
        }
        k++;
    }
    //now elements that are left out
    while(i<nL){
        a[k]=l[i];
        k++;
        i++;
    }
    while(j<nR){
        a[k]=r[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}
```

This is my **mergeSort** function to implement the merge sort algorithm.

```
void mergeSort(int* a,int n){
    //base case
    if(n<2)
        return;
    //rec case
    int mid=n/2;
    //take 2 arrays of size mid & (n-mid)
    int nL=mid;
    int nR=n-mid;
    int l[nL];
    int r[nR];
    //fill the arrays
    for(int i=0;i<mid;i++){
        l[i]=a[i];
    }
    for(int i=mid;i<n;i++){
        r[i-mid]=a[i];
    }
    //call merge sort recursively
    mergeSort(l,nL);
    mergeSort(r,nR);
    merge(l,nL,r,nR,a);
}
```

Here is the main function where I am taking an array as input and passing to the function **mergeSort**

```
int main(){
    int a[100];
    cout<<"Enter no of elements"<<endl;
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    mergeSort(a,n);
    cout<<"After sorting with merge sort"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<a[i]<<" ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Function **merge()** is merging two arrays and **mergeSort** is the function to divide the array and implement the merge sort.

I am giving this as input :

```
8
2 4 1 6 8 5 3 7
```

Output :

```
6 1006565088 2096014825 6 2098806136 2096014825 93 8
```

Comment: I don't think It would change anything. Can you please tell why you are suggesting me to do it ? What is the issue if I'm taking a as a pointer. Ultimately, I am getting base address.

Comment: `i++; a[k]=l[i];` this is wrong. Same for the other array.

Comment: Why can you please explain ?

Comment: You are using variable length arrays. VLAs are not part of C++, tgey are an extension provided by your compiler, which is not guaranteed to work and is guaranteed to crash your program when the input array is moderately large (a few megabytes). In C++ we don't use C style arrays much, std::vector provides a better alternative.

Comment: What happens when both l and r only have one element each? What elements are copied to a?

Comment: I know but it works on gcc compiler. And I don't think the problem is because of this.

Comment: If l and r has one element then it would return as per the base case condition

Comment: No, invalid results you get are not because of VLAs.

Comment: No, the base case is when a has one element (or less). It is handled by the mergeSort function. I'm talking about the merge function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55205312/10749604  i got the issue resolved.

Comment: Offtopic: You can improve readability by adding spaces around operators (`if(i < j) a[i] = a[j]`; for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)`).

Answer (score 2):

Issue is because Value of `i` and `j` is incrementing before the value is assigned to left and right arrays, in function merge.
The while loop should be:

```
while(i<nL && j<nR){
        if(l[i]<=r[j]){

            a[k]=l[i];
            i++;  //here was the mistake.
        }

        else{

            a[k]=r[j];
            j++;  // here was the mistake
        }
        k++;
    }
```